# How much time will it take a server to update half million records?

Tags: sql, time

We will be making a system that needs to take the data from the last day and update it to another system.

This update will be about half million records daily. Assuming that this is run in a good server (i don't know the exact specifications), how much time will it take to perform this task?

This will be done using SQL Server 2005

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing the specs of the server, the schema and a multitude of other parameters, no valid answer can be given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assuming that this is run in a good server (I don't know the exact specifications), how much time will it take to perform this task?

If you don't know the exact specifications, it's a *bit* hard trying to estimate.

In any case, you should be benchmarking this yourself, as there are a vast number of factors that influence it, such as:

- your disk speeds.
- your CPU grunt.
- your data schema (row size and so forth).
- and indexes on your data.
- network speeds if you're going over the wire.

Grab yourself a machine (any machine) and dummy up a database with a few million records (say, half a million per day for seven days).

Then execute your transfer however you intend to do it in your production environment.

Write down the time taken and there's your baseline. You can then tweak your environment until you get the speeds you need.

*Measure, don't guess!*

Answer (score 2):

A few seconds.

On a "good" server.

Where the data is in a file on the file system of that server already and doesn't have to come across the network.

Where a row (what you call a record in a database table) is uniquely identified and the row is not terribly wide so that a large number can be held in a page.

Where the file can be easily loaded into a staging table without a lot of transformation.

Where you only need to update a single row and not a number of foreign key relationships.

Where the table to be updated is well-indexed.

Where the contention on the destination table doesn't imply a lot of locking/blocking.

To a few hours.